# Printing duplicate number in text file to different files- python?

Tags: python

I have a text file with duplicate numbers and other data like this:

```
BMW  11   N_123
Benz 123  N_123
Ford 342  N_123

Fr   11   N_126
Benz 123  N_126
Ford 342  N_126

Toyta 11   N_124
Nissan 12  N_124
Honda  145 N_124
```

I want to write duplicate number with associate information to different text file like:

(No same number at same file)

**File 1**

```
BMW    11      N_123 
Fr     11      N_126
Toyota 124     N_124
```

**File 2**

```
Benz   123   N_123
Benz   123   N_126
Nissan 12    N_124
```

**File 3**

```
Ford  342   N_123
Ford  12    N_126
Honda 145   N_124
```

My code:

```
f = open('test.txt','rU')
for line in f.readlines():
    line=line.strip()
    #print line
    parts = line.split(" ")
    (model,data,number) = [parts[0], parts[1], parts[2]]
     all_data = [parts[0], parts[1], parts[2]]
```

I'm stuck here.. making a dictionary?, 
           I tried with IF conditional statement but I'm not getting anywhere

Comment: This isn't a very good question.  You're asking for algorithmic advice rather than asking about a particular problem you're having with this task.  I would suggest trying a handful of approaches such as reading all of the information into an array and then trying to work with the data in that format.  If that doesn't work try a new approach; but right now you've not really shown you've put much effort into trying to solve the problem.

Comment: I would suggest maintaining a `Counter` keyed by `number`. As you process each line, update the `Counter` for the current `number` and write to the file corresponding to that count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution (intentionally un-optimized to expose the logic more clearly):

```
lines = []
with open('test.txt','r') as fp:
    for line in fp.readlines():
        entry = line.rstrip().split()
        if entry:
            lines.append(entry)

file = 1
while len(lines):
    unique = []
    for item in lines:
        add = True
        for entry in unique:
            if item[2] == entry[2]:
                add = False
        if add:
            unique.append(item)
    for line in unique:
        lines.remove(line)
    with open(str(file) + '.txt', 'w') as fp:
        for item in unique:
            fp.write("{} {} {}\n".format(item[0], item[1], item[2]))
    file = file + 1
```

Answer (score 1):

So, what you want to do is duplicate the each section of `test.txt` to its own output file, right? Your code looks pretty much fine so far, I think. I'm going to copy it and make some additions that I think will solve your problem.

```
f = open('test.txt','rU')
filenum = 1
outfile = open('output' + str(filenum) + '.txt', 'w')
for line in f.readlines():
    if (len(line) == 0): # if line is blank
        outfile.close()
        filenum += 1
        outfile.open('output' + str(filenum) + '.txt', 'w')
    else:
        line=line.strip()
        #print line
        parts = line.split(" ")
        model,data,number = parts[0], parts[1], parts[2]
        outfile.write( "%s\t%s\t%s\n" % (model, data, number) )
outfile.close()
```

The first thing I added was `filenum`, which counts which output file you're printing to. Then, I open a file to begin writing to.

Now, we iterate through `test.txt`. For every line (this is within the `else` block of code), we just use the code you wrote - interpret the input file. Then, we write it to the output file (I'm using string formatting, because it's simpler to write than simply adding strings together with `+`). If we reach a blank line (as in your example - a blank line marks a separation between different sections), we close the current file, increment `filenum`, and open a new one.

Comment: No, he doesn't want any duplicates of the third parameter in any file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and clear explanation. However, I'm getting only one file as output